# DataGridView not enfocing foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, .net, sql, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to develop a business application however i am running into some problems.

I have a `DBDataSet` that is using my database as its source.

I am using VS to automatically generate DataGridView by dragging  from the datasource window and onto the form.

I have two tables. `Customer` and `Sales`. There is a one-to-one relationship between them with the id column of `Sales` Referencing id column of `Customer`.

However whenever i enter a value in id column of `Sales` that is not in the id Column of `Customer` the DataGridView doesn't do throw an exception but instead allows the data to be entered.

However when i try to enter a duplicate primary key in the same table the datagridview responds by throwing an exception.

How can i do the same for foreign key constraints.

Comment: and why exactly ur trying to insert or duplicate the primary key.. it is understood that whenever u try to repeat the primary key it will throw an exception..

Comment: I know i just used it to check if datagridview is interacting successfully with the constraints in underlying database.

Comment: now u mean one constraint is working and other is not..??

Comment: yes exactly.The primary key constraint is working fine however the foreign key constraint is not.

Comment: what i think is ur working in wrong direction.. one to one relationship exist only between column..

Answer (score 0):

ForeignKeyConstraint is not created during the import from database. Right click on Sales table in dataset view -> Add -> Relation... Select your primary and foreign key. 
"Choose what to create" first or second option. Or you can do it in code:
    this.DBDataSet.Sales.Constraints.Add(
    new  ForeignKeyConstraint(this.DBDataSet.Customer.IdColumn,
                          this.DBDataSet.Sales.IdColumn));

Comment: i have already created all constraints at the database level. I was assuming that DataGridView would automatically enforce these in the UI but it seems it does not.